# Extract fields from file with seperator inside field

Tags: file, unix, awk, field

I have a file which is comma-seperated as in this example:

```
1,2,Hello, World,3,4
2,3,Something very, different.,4,5
```

How can I extract field 3 as "Hello, World" and "Something very, different." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in general you cannot.

If the rest of the fields are numeric, you can extract the alphabetical fields.  Or, if you know that there are 5 fields and first two and last two are not composite you can extract the fields in the middle.

Here is a script for the latter

```
$ awk -F, '{line=sep=""   
            for(i=3;i<NF-1;i++) {line=line sep $i; sep=FS} 
            print line}' confused

Hello, World
Something very, different.
```

Comment: Might it be possible to define some static number of fields (in the example 5) and have it not cut the last fields but always leave the "," for fieldnumber 3?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[0-9],|,[0-9]' '{print $3}' file
Hello, World
Something very, different.
```

This works by making the field separator any digit that touches a comma,  preserving anything else in the middle as the third field.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $3, $4}' file
Hello, World              
Something very, different.
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^([^,]+,){2}|(,[^,]){2}$/,"")} 1' file
Hello, World
Something very, different.

$ sed -r 's/^([^,]+,){2}|(,[^,]){2}$//g' file
Hello, World
Something very, different.
```

Comment: Can you please explain that a bit?

Comment: it just removes the first and last 2 non-comma/comma strings and prints whats left, i.e. the string in the middle. Going forward - you might want to not accept the first answer you get to questions as it discourages others from posting answers that might be better in some way.

Comment: thanks - I feel that the answer provided above is a good one and it also allows the combination of other fields into output but still works. Example: awk -F, '{line=sep=""; for(i=3;i<NF-1;i++) {line=line sep $i; sep=FS} print $1,$2,line,$5,$6}' confused

Comment: Printing the rest of the fields is absolutely trivial but you didn't say you wanted that in your question - you said you wanted the output to be just the strings from the middle. It's always a good idea to show in your question what you REALLY want in your output, otherwise you're likely to get what you said you wanted.

Comment: Trivial for those who are familiar with regexp, sure. I am unfortunately not. Both your answers are correct and solves the question asked in regarding to printing that "third" field.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, I'm just saying in general you should wait a few hours before selecting an answer as otherwise people will just skip your question since it's already answered and so you might miss the opportunity to see a better answer. Printing the other fields would have nothing to do with a regexp, btw.

Comment: I see your point and will keep the questions I ask open longer in the future. Thanks for the kind pointers!